# Flutter app simple login page , iam getting this error after selecting acc "'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '() => void'"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I am building a simple login app on Flutter, google account selection popups and I select the account but login fails.

[DEBUG CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K86XU.png)

[Login Page Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u0ow.png)

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is (i think) what happens after you log in, you r code goes on to return the loggedInUi function's results.
which has a build tree which contains an ActionChip
in the onPressed you supply a function there, but you call it directly (it returns a Future, thats why your error says what it says)

instead, in the onPressed supply something like this:

```
() {
 yourFunctionCall(Parameters);
}
```

which would supply a void Function that just calls your function

Comment: thank you.
i did it like this :
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<GoogleSignInController>(context, listen: false)
                  .logOut();
            }